# Supporting multi google drive in one application?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have **server** which **has credentials** of several google drives(**client_id, client_secret, refresh token** for each google drive which generated from google console). I have clients. Whenever some client wants to upload, I choose one google drive, make authentication and send url with access token to a client, so it can upload. It works with single google drive. However if I want to give that time to some another client, another google drive's url for uploading, google does not allowing to do so. Below is log when client can not upload:

```
 "kind": "drive#permission",
 "etag": "\some_encrypted_string_here"\"",
 "id": "anyoneWithLink",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/folder_id/permissions/anyoneWithLink",
 "role": "reader",
 "type": "anyone",
 "withLink": true
```

Does google drive allows for one application at the same time make several authentication for several google drives, getting urls and use it by clients to upload file?

Any help kindly appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Does google drive allows for one application at the same time make several authentication for several google drives, getting urls and use it by clients to upload file?**

Yes it does.

Comment: Thanks for answer. However I put timer in my app every hour it refreshes access tokens to 3 google drives. I'm able to upload only to 3rd google drive. For other two I cannot and json text above in question is coming